# Jinja2 - Table row manipulation issue with if statement

Tags: python, jinja2, python-docx

I'm trying to change my word document tagging from: (sorry I don't have enough reputation to embed images :()

[current template format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hXKj.png)

to something like this (I've used the python-docx jinja helper '{%tr if' but open to using anything!)

[future template format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuqEo.png)

- The main reason for this is to have clean blocks that I can then copy/paste and move around large tables. In the current template format I need to copy/paste blocks then tweak the remaining if condition parts from the rows above.
- What I've proposed doesn't work, the parser complains. If I move banana_condition2 to the start of the line below (before Banana) then if banana_condition2 fails I end up with a blank row which I don't want.

Thanks in advance!